# Least time to cross water swimming and running

Tags: calculus, optimization

There's a calculus problem I love that Blank & Krantz$^\color{red}{\ast}$ attribute to [E. V. Huntington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Vermilye_Huntington):

> **Problem 54.** A person wants to cross a circular pool to reach a point diametrically opposite to their current position. They will swim directly to a point partway around the circle and then run the rest of the way to reach the opposite side. They swim at a constant rate $u$ and run at a rate $v$. How quickly can the person get across the pool?

---

The reason I love it, aside from some fun geometry in setting up the function to optimize, is that in this problem, more than any other I have seen, the classification of the criticial point is counterintuitive to me. It turns out that if $u < v$, then there is a critical point that would have the person swim partway and run the rest of the way ... but it is a *maximum* for the function giving the time to get across. And if $u > v$, there is no critical point. So in order to get across most efficiently, by minimizing the time, it is always best to either swim directly across or else run the whole way around. There is no circumstance under which it is optimal to use a combination of swimming and running.

Now I figured that this is somehow specific to the shape being a circle. So I tried the same problem with a square, starting in the middle of one side and trying to reach a point directly opposite, and I see that it very well can be optimal to swim to a point on the side of the pool and then run the rest of the way around, if the person runs faster than they swim.

But this gets me thinking: you could do the same with a hexagon, and octagon, etc. At some point, the situation should be resembling the circle enough that it is optimal either only to swim or only to run.

So my question is really the most general: given an even, concave function f(x) connecting the points $(-r,0)$ and $(r,0)$, we can reflect the graph of $f$ around the $x$-axis to make a "pool." Under what conditions on $f$ is it never optimal to use a combination of swimming/running?

But barring an answer to that, I am happy to know which regular $n$-gons would have this property, and maybe some insight into what makes them special.

---

<sub>$\color{red}{\ast}$ Brian E. Blank, Steven G. Krantz, [Single Variable Calculus](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Calculus%3A+Single+and+Multivariable%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118207659) (2nd edition), Wiley, September 2011.</sub>

Comment: Can you attach a sketch? I'm not 100% sure I can follow the original problem

Comment: Reminds me of [Fermat's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle)

Comment: You might want symmetry about the $y$-axis too. Otherwise it's two separate problems and one of them will dominate the other.

Comment: "to reach the opposite side" $\to$ "to reach the opposite point".

Comment: Re: the picture. Someone asked essentially this book problem and there is a nice picture in the answer here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556636/what-is-the-minimum-time-to-get-from-x-to-q-on-a-circle-by-running-swimming-or

(But my question is different: about generalizing this problem rather than solving it)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, see my comment from a few minutes before yours. I already know how to solve the problem in the textbook. I want to know how it generalizes.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Wiley 2011. Here:

https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Calculus:+Single+and+Multivariable,+2nd+Edition-p-9780470453605

And wow, just realized they have the ToC for the wrong book showing there!

Comment: So, closed with no comments about why it is closed? I addressed the comment about the related question that is not a duplicate. And my original post was already clear that I did not want a solution to the problem at that other post.

Comment: It seems like an interesting question. For now I vote to leave it open. Something I rarely do. But please reduce the amount of text and add some formal maths.